# Find Max Product of All Possible Paths in A Binary Tree

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-tree, computer-science, pseudocode

I have trouble writing the pseudocode of the algorithm that finds the maximum product of all possible paths in a binary tree.

[Problem is described in this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkgIK.jpg)

Comment: I don't think this is a place to just look for a solution to what appears to be a homework problem. Why not post what you have already and maybe someone can help improve it or point out something your doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The fact that it can be any path, and the fact that there are negative numbers, those things complicate this.  Otherwise it would be a simple recursion.

But there is still a recursion here.

Given a subtree that is just one level, like so:

```
 A
B C
```

Then you have the 6 possibilities of A * B * C, or A * B, or A * C, or A, or B, or C.

Given a larger tree like so:

```
  A
 X Y
```

where X and Y are trees in their own right, then consider that you have the similar 6 possible combinations:

A

A * (any potential product from X that includes the root node of X) * (any potential product from Y that includes the root node of Y)

A * (any potential product from X that includes the root node of X)

A * (any potential product from Y that includes the root node of Y)

Any potential product from X

Any potential product from Y

Any single one of those products can end up being the largest.

So now you can write a recursive function that incorporates those 6 possibilities, and call the function starting from the root node.  In the function you will calculate all 6 of those products (calling your function recursively) and if any of those products are bigger than the global max, you have a new global max.

Comment: Cool! Seems a brute force solution to me. I don't want to think about its time complexity but can you suggest the same?

Comment: It will visit every node exactly once so it's O(n) on the visiting, within the recursive function you are iterating through the products returned from leafs not sure what that complexity is, So yeah, could be exponential complexity, although I suspect you cannot do better.  The recursive function is a bit tricky, you have to return to callers the set of products that include the root node and you have to make sure you cover all the bases.

Comment: Sometimes, always largest from subtrees isn't always the answer needed if root is a negative number and taking largest of subtrees from an array of positives and negatives.